# incompatible results of QTableWidget.selectedItems() with multi select

Tags: qt, pyqt, multi-select, qtablewidget

I am using **PyQt** table widget with the following settings.

- SelectionBehavior set to 1 (selecting rows only)
- SelectionMode set to 3 (ExtendedSelection)
- Columns are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
- Rows are A, B, C

When I use **Ctrl** to select the first two rows, QTableWidget.selectedItems() returns the following list:

A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8

However, if I use **Shift** to select the first two rows, QTableWidget.selectedItems() returns the following list:

A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3, A4, B4, A5, B5, A6, B6, A7, B7, A8, B8

It becomes difficult to predict the order of the list. 
I see that, capturing the key press event and process the list accordingly is one way. 
Is there any simpler way to overcome such scenario?

Thanks for the help.

Navin

Comment: I have a flag set on the 3rd column of the of each row. A3, B3. However, As the list differs each type of selection, I am not sure which index to look for.

Comment: currently, I am iterating all the selected items and checking if the column id is 2 then processing it. but if the selected list is big, then I will require to iterate all the items, which is not necessary. So I am looking for a simpler/optimized solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the selected items in a particular column, you can use the [selectedRows](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows) method of the table's [selection model](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). But note that this will only work for rows where **all** columns are selected. Also, for extended selections, the order of the returned indexes may not not always be the same. So to get fully consistent results, the indexes can be sorted first:

```
indexes = tablewidget.selectionModel().selectedRows(column)
for index in sorted(indexes):
    item = tablewidget.itemFromIndex(index)
    print(item.text())
```